# How to fill author or user name using python shell?

Tags: python, django

- Language: Python

I was trying to fill my author field using python shell,
in shell i was typing this:

```
Post.objects.create(title='second blog post', author="yashm",
        body='done via python shell')
```

I already created a superuser named as 'yashm', but still im getting this error (see picture)

[image]

## Models.py file

from django.db import models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]
```

Comment: you must provide an instance of the user, but not the username.  u = User.objects.get(username='yashm') ; post = Post.objects.create(author=u, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the user instance first.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.create_user(username='yashm',first_name='yashm',
           last_name='yashm', email='')
```

And then you will be able create your post object:

`Post.objects.create(title='second blog post', author=user, body='done via python shell')`